# iPhone UIScrollview Pages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal scrollview with :

```
[journal setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

I've been using a custom method to scroll to the right on the touch of a button

```
[journal setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320,0) animated:YES];
```

Is there an already existing method for working with pages and how do I find it?

Thanks,
Rd

Comment: What do you mean by "working with pages"?

Comment: You don't mention what's happening (or not happening) seems to me that should work... to advance a page on each button touch. What actually happens?

Comment: @Moshe, thankss.  @Wex it works, but it's 4 pages wide and I want a one method fits all instead of sending page 1 to 0,460 page 2 to 320,460 and so on.

Comment: Moshe, I went back to accept more answers but sometimes there are no acceptable answers.  68% is what it will have to stay at for now.

Comment: @rd42 If the answers are not acceptable, then don't accept them. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for something like `[myScrollView scrollToPage:3]`, then no, there is no built in method. It's also pretty easy to roll your own if you really want something explicit. Assuming a horizontally paged UIScrollView:

```
- (void)scrollUIScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView toPage:(NSInteger)page {

    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat pageHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    CGRect scrollTarget = CGRectMake(page * pageWidth, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:scrollTarget animated:YES];
}
```

Okay, the method name is terrible, but that's the basic idea. I may be nicer in a Category on UIScrollView.

Comment: Exactly what I had just started looking for.  THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brilliant [blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html) on paged UIScrollView by Matt Gallagher. I used it in a project of mine, required some tweaking but otherwise was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The [`UIPageControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) works similar to the way that the iPhone's SpringBoard (home screen) functions.

Comment: UIPageControl only shows the dots. It's not terribly interesting. It's the UIScrollView that's doing the heavy lifting.